# Can System.Security.Cryptography be added to Microsoft Access

Tags: encryption, ms-access-2007

We would like to decrypt data stored in Microsoft Access.

Without getting into too much detail we have a Web Form, written in PHP, that saves Form Data (encrypted) to a MySQL table.  MS Access copies that Form Data (via an ODBC link) from MySQL to its own table.  I am following this post [Decrypt PHP encrypted string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224453/decrypt-php-encrypted-string-in-c-sharp) thinking that VBA and VB.net should be close enough that I can work out the errors.  But I don't see System.Security.Cryptography listed in 'Access database Object Library'. Is it possible to add System.Security.Cryptography to MS Access and if so how?  If MS Access doesn't support adding System.Security.Cryptography, do you have any ideas on how to decrypt data within MS Access that was encrypted in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a C#/VB.Net library that simply encrypts/decrypts data, expose it as COM and call it from Access. It's very simple to do and I've successfully done this with various projecs. Rich Newman has a very good article on how to do this [here](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/08/25/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-access/).

Comment: In case this might help others I started with Rich Newman's article that Eddie Paz mentioned and I used/modified the script found [here](http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=2576) which uses PHP and VB.NET.