# C# Encrypt Rijndael 256

Tags: c#, encryption

I use this example from stackoverflow :
[C# Encryption to PHP Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873878/c-sharp-encryption-to-php-decryption)

GENERATE FUNCTION :

```
    public static void GenerateKeyIV(out string key, out string IV)
    {
        var rj = new RijndaelManaged()
        {
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            KeySize = 256,
            BlockSize = 256,
            //FeedbackSize = 256
        };
        key = Convert.ToBase64String(rj.Key);
        IV = Convert.ToBase64String(rj.IV);
    }
```

Encrypt 2 FUNCTION :

```
    public static string Encrypt2(string prm_text_to_encrypt, string prm_key, string prm_iv)
    {
        var sToEncrypt = prm_text_to_encrypt;

        var rj = new RijndaelManaged()
        {
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            KeySize = 256,
            BlockSize = 256,
            //FeedbackSize = 256
        };

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key);
        var IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv);
        //var key = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_key);
        //var IV = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_iv);

        var encryptor = rj.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

        var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        var toEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sToEncrypt);

        csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        var encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

        return (Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
    }
```

MAIN PROGRAM :

```
        Enc2.GenerateKeyIV(out key, out iv);
        string encrypted_url = Enc2.Encrypt2("test tekst todo",key,iv);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted_url);
```

==> iv = cCJNWmwOtIBg6zM7Mz/JQV/lcauNMWf50nQk1ZiEKZ4=

==> key = gNDiEqWk7aGhj1+A2EURW5CPurxHPcfy3F2FTa4peC0=

==> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.

==> the key and iv seem to be properly generated, I dont understand why I receive this error.

Comment: There you have it. You encoded the key and IV to Base64, but decoded it as ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your encryption method `Enc2.Encrypt2()`. It may be using a different block size from what you specified in your IV generation method.

**UPDATE:**

Do this:

```
public static string Encrypt2(string prm_text_to_encrypt, string prm_key, string prm_iv)
{
        var sToEncrypt = prm_text_to_encrypt;

        var rj = new RijndaelManaged()
        {
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            KeySize = 256,
            BlockSize = 256,
            //FeedbackSize = 256
        };

        var key = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_key);
        var IV = Convert.FromBase64String(prm_iv);

        var encryptor = rj.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

        var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        var toEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sToEncrypt);

        csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

        var encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();

        return (Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
}
```

Comment: Also fix your Enc2.Encrypt2() method call, you are using "iv" lowercase, where your variable is upper-case (IV)

Comment: Works perfectly but what is the major difference ? Convert.FromBase64string ?!

Comment: Yeah, exactly :P. In your generation algorithm you are encoding the values with base64, so you need to convert them back to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use below encryption Method as Reference

```
public string Encrypt(String plainText, String key)
     {
         var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
         return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
     }
     public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
     {
         return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
             .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
     }
     public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
     {
         var keyBytes = new byte[16];
         var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
         Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
         return new RijndaelManaged
         {
             Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
             Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
             KeySize = 128,
             BlockSize = 128,
             Key = keyBytes,
             IV = keyBytes
         };
     }
```